# Threejs Globe, how to rotate to a specific lat/long?

Tags: three.js, webgl-globe

I'm using ThreeJS Globe Visualization, and want the globes starting rotation to be a certain country. I have the lat/long coordinates and I've tried to use the
Globe.rotation.x,y and z. It dosen't work.

Here is my code:

```
const p = POLAR_2_CARTESIAN( my.latitude, my.longitude, my.altitude / EARTH_RADIUS_KM, Globe.getGlobeRadius() );
Globe.rotation.x = p.x;
Globe.rotation.y = p.y;
Globe.rotation.z = p.z;
```